# .htaccess vs chmod

Tags: web, apache-2.2

what is the difference between .htaccess and chmod?

and what is the meaning of if someone say's that this file/directory is chmodded?

how to rewrite my .htaccess file on server?

how to change mod rights?

and how to use them in web server?

```
 1  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 2     RewriteEngine On
 3     RewriteBase /webcpy/
 4     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 5     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 6     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 7     RewriteRule . /webcpy/index.php [L]
 8  </IfModule>
```

what is the meaning of line 5or 6

Answer (score 1):

htaccess :  reflected in its name - was to allow per-directory access control from web 
follow the link for configuring htaccess : http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess/1

chmod : change file access permissions(for read, write and execute), for the user, group, other on the operating system